# Why motherboard manufacturer's logo is not showing up during booting up of windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I use a gigabyte h310 motherboard.Before reinstalling Windows 10 the motherboard manufacturers (Gigabyte) logo was being display during the Windows 10 boot process however after reinstallation Windows 10 stock boot logo is being displayed. why does that happen?

N.B- I am using UEFI mode. It just that it looks a lot cooler with the "Insist on ultra durable" logo. That's why I wanted to restore that logo.

Comment: Are you using `Legacy Mode` or `UEFI Mode`?  You should edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: It may be you wrote over the Manufacturer's logo with a standard Windows 10 ISO file.

Comment: logo is probably optional in the bios settings. or your display may be too slow to sync.